# Is there way that iOS 6 will determine images created for itself?

Tags: ios, uiimage, retina-display, iphone-5

Normally for Standard and Retina display we create two images `Image.png` and `Image@2x.png` and iOS detemines which one to use based on device in the app.

Now, with iPhone5 we have new resolution, so is there any new way to use same method and diplay images with higher resolution specifically for **iPhone5**?

Comment: Take a look at to Ben Claytons answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532527/549592

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images for iphone 5 retina display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532405/images-for-iphone-5-retina-display)

Answer (score 1):

Just pont to the iPhone 5 friendly image name you want to use. For example, I use images like this: **myiPhone5Image-568h.png**