# ios 6 : background imageview in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

In my iphone application I am using a background image bg.png (for retina size bg@2x.png).
I updated xcode to 4.5. Now I need to arrange the UI for fit into iPhone 5 - 4 inch display. Since the frame height will become 568, I need to fix my background also having a height 568.
I added a image named bg-568h@2x.png in my app. But Iam not getting this image for iPhone 6 simulator in xcode. Is there any way to get this image? or how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think, this can be helpful for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532405/images-for-iphone-5-retina-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this dynamic code....

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

or

This creates a memory leak. Either change initWithPatternImage to colorWithPatternImage, or assign your UIColor object to a variable and properly release it:

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = color;
[color release];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting bg-568h@2x.png to be the background image, and set the ImageView scaling to Aspect Fill?