# How to addapt iphone background?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to developing and I am trying to find how to have a different background image for different iphones (4s 5 5s ect...) I did manage to have a background image but its the same in all simulators so it only fits the Iphone 6 plus 
any ideas on how I could do this?

thank you

Comment: Provide details about what you did so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use xcassets for your ressources :

[image]

If you don't you can add one :

[image]

You can add your images in an image set specific to devices like below :

[image]

You just have to configure the right panel accordingly (selecting device specific and choosing all that you need) :

[image]

One drawback : 
The .jpg support seems to not be compatible with iOS7. Big images in png are... big.

Comment: thank you for answering but I can't seem to find the same things as you, this is what I have (version 6.1) http://imgur.com/8FOLbVs

Comment: I think that's the IB interface not the xcassets interface, I added picture above to clarify my answer